# Google Spreadsheet Script Write Data to Multiple Spreadsheets using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to expand on the script from:
"Tutorial: Writing Spreadsheet data using JavaScript Objects"
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/writing_spreadsheet_data

I have implemented this script onto our own spreadsheet and am able to read our source spreadsheet and write to a target spreadsheet. Unfortunately I have reached the limit of that tutorial, which coincides precisely with the extent of my knowledge of javascript.

Our goals:
1) Instead of writing data to a sheet that matches the "department" used in the tutorial, we need to write to a specific target spreadsheet with one sheet that matches the department. 
2) We need to loop the script to write each department to a unique spreadsheet.

For our purposes we have about 100 "departments", the result we are looking for should be 100 spreadsheets - 1 for each department [just like the sheets that are created in the tutorial] The script does not need to dynamically create a new spreadsheet, although that would be cool...we just need to have it write to the appropriate spreadsheet.

Any help/advice or direction is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need to store somewhere is a mapping from department name to spreadsheet ID. This could be done by creating a special sheet in your master spreadsheet that contains that mapping:

```
Department     Spreadsheet Id
Sales          123
HR             456
```

When you are ready to write out the data you can lookup the spreadsheet ID for the given department. You can use [SpreadsheetApp.openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheetapp.html#openById) to open the spreadsheet and write data to it.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Seems to make sense to have this mapping list you mention on the spreadsheet where the script is written. We are then opening the source sheet, and pulling data by dept, and placing on a target sheet....I think I'm going to need someone to help me write this one...starting to become a stretch for me.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm new to Javascript, google sheets and this site. but thought I'd share something that you might find of interest. It's a script I made to move data from a sheet, into various target sheets, based on month.

It works by going through the `targetSheetNames`, one by one and seeing if the month value of a bit of data matches the index number of the sheet name in the array.

So in this instance, array goes from 0-11, which is handy, as months in Javascript go 0-11 too.

For your purposes, you'll probably have to add in some more bits, to check it's the right data etc. But it gives you an example of moving data to multiple sheets, within the same spreadsheet.

```
function splitByMonth(){

  var targetSheetNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]; // Sheet names, in month order. Order is important. Name is not. Sheets must exist. This will not create them.
  var sourceSheet = "Archive"; // Name of sheet with data in it.
   var dateColumn = 1; // Column number with date in it. A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, etc

  var ss, sheet, values, valuesLength, counter, archive = [];


  for (var i = 0; i < targetSheetNames.length; i++){

 ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
 values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 valuesLength = values.length;
 counter = 1; // This starts at one because it assumes a header row.
 archive = [];

  while (counter < values.length){


    var d = new Date(values[counter][dateColumn - 1]);
    var m = d.getMonth();

    if (m == i  ){

      archive.push(values.splice(counter, 1)[0]); 
    }

    else

    {     
      counter++;
    }

  }  

  var archiveLength = archive.length;
  if (!archiveLength) {continue;}
  var dataSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetSheet = dataSs.getSheetByName(sourceSheetKeys[i]);
  var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  var requiredRows = lastRow + archiveLength - targetSheet.getMaxRows();
  if (requiredRows > 0) targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(lastRow, requiredRows);
  targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, archiveLength, archive[0].length).setValues(archive);
 }

}
```